# Region bounded by two curves

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Suppose we're told that *$C$ is the closed curve of the region bounded by $y = x$ and $y = x^2$*. Would we know that this is the region $x^2 \le y \le x$ without sketching? I know it is a simple to sketch this one, but when I'm given complicated regions I'm looking for a way to recognize the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the endpoints of the bounded region:

$$x^2=x\iff x=0,\,1\implies 0\le x\le 1\;$$

Now, do the proper calculations for $\;0\le x\le1\;$ :

$$x^2>x\,,\,\,x\neq0\iff x>1$$

and we get that in fact $\;x^2\le x\;$ when $\;x\in[0,1]\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

Find the intersections, in this case, $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. By continuity, you can check if $f>g$ or $f<g$ evaluating in only one point in finite regions, in this case the interval $(0,1)$.